# IntelliJ Autocomplete Not Showing PHPDoc

Tags: php, intellij-idea

When I use autocomplete in IntelliJ with the PHP plugin active it comes up correctly. The problem is that I'm missing the documentation for the function calls. I know IntelliJ can "see" it because if I go over $this->connection->autocommit("foo"); and hit ctrl-Q I see the docs I'm looking for.

How do I...

1. Get the PHPDocs to automatically appear when I'm doing autocomplete.
2. Get the PHPDocs to automatically appear when I'm hovering over something.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Autopopup documentation in](http://img407.imageshack.us/img407/2683/20130410111358.png)...
   Note that it works only for the explicit completion, when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.
2. You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> when completing to get the popup. Automatic documentation on mouse however is not available in the current IDE version, but it may appear later as this feature was [recently implemented in the platform](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-5999).

Comment: Oh man after reading that comment thread I'm disappointed it's taken this long to get such a simple common feature into Intellij :C At least they listen, after a fashion.